# Implement WPA2-Enterprise on Arduino WiFi shield

Tags: arduino, wpa

I've just bought an Arduino WiFi shield called "RedFly", which support WPA-TKIP but my school wifi is WPA2-Enterprise + PEAP (MSCHAPv2).

Is there a way, and how to implement myself the support of this WIFI security please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working with a different shield. Attempting to get the same result as you, connection to a MSCHAP(v2) network.

Just received word back from the manufacturer of my shield I purchased and it does support MS-CHAPv2.That's great news, now we are just troubleshooting with the network admin!

Stefen Kaur
smkaur@bsu.edu

Comment: Hello,

The WiFi module only supports WPA2-PSK (no Enterprise/EAP) and I have no information if RedPine will add this feature.

Mit freundlichen Gruessen / Best Regards
Andreas Watterott
- CTO -

Comment: This answer isn't very useful as-is. You should consider going into more detail, or at least the name of the module you used.